# Unable to run App on my HTC wildfire

Tags: android

Hey I have been having trouble trying to get a little app I was doing to run on my HTC wildfire. I have upgraded to 2.2 awhile back and I have enabled USB debugging on the phone
and enabled debugging to true in the manifest, but my device still doesn't show up in the list when I go to run the app. Anyone out there run into this problem?

Comment: may be u have to re-install htc usb modemdriver or htc sync..

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing using Eclipse on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development.

1. Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

For Gusty/Hardy, edit the file to read:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

For Dapper, edit the file to read:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

1. Now execute:
   chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Please check this link for details: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#VendorIds

Comment: For my HTC Wildfire S A510E, I needed to add SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0cb0", MODE="0666", GROUP="my-user-group" into /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules in my Ubuntu 14.04.1. You can find the full list here http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/android (in French)